# How to explain my bank statements on Schengen visit visa application

Tags: proof-provenance-of-funds, schengen-visas

I am applying for Schengen visit visa through France. My bank statement shows an amount other than the monthly salary. How should I justify the amount in my visa application? It is a cash loan repayment, transacted more than a year back in India. My friend who borrowed the money has returned the amount, paying it in Kuwaiti dinars to my Kuwait bank account.

How should I explain this in order to avoid refusals/appeals? I have only a few days before for my holidays with family.

Comment: One way might be to also show bank statements from when you made the loan and prior statements showing the steady regular savings building up the surplus you were able to loan your friend.

Comment: Did you make him sign a promissory note?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus.. tks for the response. I do not have any signed promissory note.

Comment: Is it material?

Comment: If this was a year ago, and if the account shows a good pattern of incomes and expenditures since then, there should be no problem.

Comment: Have you (or your family) applied before, or is this the first time applying for a Schengen visa?

Comment: @ Dorothy .. my daughter had travelled to Italy as part of her school trip. We as family going for the first time.

Comment: Even if it was yesterday, you can just add a note: "Yesterday, a friend paid back a loan to the amount of xxxxx. Please disregard this payment when you look at my overall financial situation, since there will be no similar payments in the future". If your finances without that payment are fine, _and_ you tell them what it is, there should be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the monthly salary payments are around (in some circumstances there can be more variations then in other) the amount you claim to earn, the officers evaluating your visa application will probably not care about the size of the deposited amount(s) at other times in relation to your salary. one possible exception being if you have a deposit that you claim is a loan repayment for an amount several times your annual income.

If you can show a bank statement from when your friend borrowed the money, i.e. a withdrawal of a similar amount (since there's a different currency involved, it probably can't be exactly the same) I would consider that sufficient evidence that the money is yours, and not a deposit of someone made into your account to make it look like you have enough funds.

Comment: I want to be cautious as my application to U.K. Visit was refused on the same issue..